# how to convert non-unicode to unicode?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, unicode, non-unicode

In my database there is a field which type is of type "varchar" and it cannot save my alphabet, so the value is for example - "|^є^Ѓ¦`ѓЇ ^єЋ^", and I want to convert it to unicode when I retrieve the data. How canI do that? Is it possible in JavaScript? or vb.net?

IMPORTANT: I do not have access to change the column type in the database.

Comment: I don't now how the value was inserted, I just have database where data is save so, I also don't know what encoding is used. I think that it is charged encoding,because database type is varchar

Comment: Check the `COLLATIONPROPERTY` of that field, and see what CodePage or LCID was used. Then you can use: `Dim OriginalEncoding as Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding([CodePage])`.

Comment: When *you* insert `ႠႡႢაბგ`, what is the result in the database?

Comment: when I insert `ႠႡႢაბგ` , result in the database is `??????`

Comment: First task, and only you can do it, it is to find the original encoding. Ask or try decoding with many decoders. Note: Unicode is also just a decoded (so wee it as virtual data). Probably you should also decide in which form (which encoder) you need to put your unicode data.